# Visual Studio Code auto formatter not getting configured

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, formatting

I have recently started working in VueJS. I am using Visual Studio Code for that. There are some rules like trailing comma and Single quotes in tslint.json.
But whenever I am using VS code auto formatter, it is removing all the trailing commas and replacing single quotes to double-quotes.

I made some changes in setting.json as well following some other posts, but nothing is getting changed. Formatter is behaving the same.

Currently, my setting.json looks like this.

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
    "typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
    "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.trailingComma": "all",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "vscode-typescript"
}
```

Quick help is really appreciated.

Comment: try putting the prettier specific configuration in .editorconfig or prettier.config.js like documented [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettiers-settings)

Comment: I have updated changes in .editorconfig too. Still, while formatting Vs code behaving the same old way as if nothing changed.

Comment: @AshishBisht Can you please provide a specific example of an instance in which this phenomenon occurs? Something like a 'before' and 'after'.

Comment: @ifconfig So, whenever I am hitting shift+alt+f 
1. all my single quotes are getting converted into double quotes 2. Trailing commas are getting removed 3. parenthesis around the arrow function arguments are getting removed. And many more.

Comment: To prevent all this I am trying to edit the configuration by making changes in setting.json and .editorconfig but nothing is working

Comment: I meant a sample code segment for before and after. It's hard to tell what you're describing.